# Problems with Output in Java

Tags: java, string, uppercase, lowercase

I have no idea why my output is not coming out correct. For example, if the input is "Running is fun" then the output should read "Is running fun". However, the output I am getting is "Iunning".

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Problem1 {
  public static void main( String [] args ) {

 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("Enter text: ");
 String sentence = sc.nextLine();

  int space = sentence.indexOf(" ");
 String firstWord = sentence.substring(0, space + 1);
 String removedWord = sentence.replaceFirst(firstWord, "");

String newSentence = removedWord.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + 
firstWord.substring(1).toLowerCase();

System.out.println(""); 
System.out.println( newSentence );

  }
}
```

Comment: At what point does your code *first* not work the way you expected it to?

Comment: @GBlodgett has a great analysis; to get you moving in the right direction maybe look at `String.split` and split on " ".

Answer (score 1):

`removedWord.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()` this line adds the capitalized first letter of the second word in the sentence. (`I`)

`firstWord.substring(1).toLowerCase();` adds every letter of the first word to the end of the sentence. (`unning`)

Thus this creates the output of `Iunning`. You need to add the rest of `removedWord` to the `String`, as well as a space, and the first letter of `firstWord`, as a lower case letter at the space in `removedWord`. You can do this more by using [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) to find the space, and then using [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) to add on `firstWord.toLowerCase()` right after the index of the space:

```
removedWord = removedWord.substring(0, removedWord.indexOf(" ")) + " " + 
              firstWord.toLowerCase() + 
              removedWord.substring(removedWord.indexOf(" ") + 1, 
              removedWord.length());
String newSentence = removedWord.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + 
                 removedWord.substring(1, removedWord.length());
```

Output:

```
Is running fun
```

Comment: According to the OP the desired output is „Is running fun“

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that

```
firstWord.substring(1).toLowerCase()
```

Is not working as you expect it to work.

Given `firstWord` is `“Running“` as in your example, then

```
”Running“.substring(1)
```

Returns ”unning“

```
”unning“.toLowerCase()
```

Obviously returns ”unning“

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at `String newSentence`. You not make the right combination of `firstWord` and `removedWord`.

This is how should be for your case:

```
String newSentence = removedWord.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()  // I
                + removedWord.substring(1,2) + " "      // s
                + firstWord.toLowerCase().trim() + " "  // running
                + removedWord.substring(2).trim();      // fun
```

EDIT(add new solution. credits @andy):

```
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");

words[1] = words[1].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + words[1].substring(1);

String newSentence = words[1] + " " 
                + words[0].toLowerCase() + " " 
                + words[2].toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works properly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter text: ");
    String sentence = sc.nextLine();

    int space1 = sentence.indexOf(' ');
    int space2 = sentence.indexOf(' ', space1 + 1);

    if (space1 != -1 &&  space2 != -1) {
        String firstWord = sentence.substring(0, space1 + 1);
        String secondWord = sentence.substring(space1 + 1, space2 + 1);

        StringBuilder newSentence = new StringBuilder(sentence);
        newSentence.replace(0, secondWord.length(), secondWord);
        newSentence.replace(secondWord.length(), secondWord.length()+ firstWord.length(), firstWord);
        newSentence.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(newSentence.charAt(0)));
        newSentence.setCharAt(secondWord.length(), Character.toLowerCase(newSentence.charAt(secondWord.length())));

        System.out.println(newSentence);
    }
}
```